# Complex SSIS expression

Tags: ssis, expression

I have the following expression

```
CASE     WHEN  NVL(FLAG,'N') = 'Y'      
 THEN NVL(HRS,0) * 7    ELSE       
 WHRS  END
```

I tried to write it within SSIS expression

```
(isnull(FLAG)? "N":FLAG)== "Y"? ((ISNULL(HRS)?0:HRS)* 7 ):WHRS
```

But it did'nt work ?

How can I modify it using SSIS expression ?

Comment: `Didn't work` - did it throw any error or results were unexpected?

Comment: Looks good to me.  Why do you say it didn't work?

Comment: In the line connecting the previous component and the derived column, double click and look at the Metadata. Please edit your question to specify the type, length and precision for FLAG, HRS and WHRS. I expect you're getting a data type mismatch